# AppleScript: if selection empty, select all

Tags: macos, applescript

I've made many AppleScript module for TextWrangler but this time I face a "stupid" problem:
The idea: if nothing is selected in the text, set the selection to all the text.
I've made many tests, without any succes. Here is the last one:

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    set my_selection to (get selection)
    set nb_mot to count words of (my_selection)

    if nb_mot < 1 then
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "a" using command down
            display dialog "Select all"
            delay 1
        end tell
        set my_selection to (get selection)

        delay 2
        set nb_new_mot to count words of (my_selection)
        display dialog "After select all " & nb_new_mot
    end if

    set var_1 to (replace "(" using "(" searching in my_selection options {search mode:literal, starting at top:false, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false})
end tell
```

When I select a part of the text, it's okay. When nothing is selected, I enter the `if` block, but this give me an empty selection.

Any idea how I can grab only the selected text when there is something and perform a select all and copy that if no text is selected?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get an empty selection, i.e. when nothing is selected and `set my_selection to (get selection)` *returns*, e.g., `insertion point before character 1 of text document 1`, the `if` *statement* block fails with the

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using command down
```

portion of the *code* because **TextWrangler** doesn't have focus.

The `keystroke` *command* goes to whatever has focus, so before you have **System Events** `keystroke` something, `activate` the target first, e.g.:

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    activate
    -- delay 1 -- # Uncomment and or adjust the value of the 'delay' command as/if necessary.
    set my_selection to (get selection)
    set nb_mot to count words of (my_selection)

    if nb_mot < 1 then
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "a" using command down
            display dialog "Select all"
...
```

---

That said, you can omit the `activate` *command* and use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    set my_selection to selection
    set nb_mot to count words of my_selection

    if nb_mot < 1 then
        set my_selection to characters 1 thru -1 of text document 1
        set nb_new_mot to count words of my_selection
    end if

    set var_1 to (replace "(" using "(" searching in my_selection options {search mode:literal, starting at top:false, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false})
end tell
```

Note for clarity, I've remove the `display dialog` and `delay` *commands* along with all of **System Events** *code*, and other unnecessary *code*, as the following line of *code* is all that's necessary if the `nb_mot is < 1`:

```
set my_selection to characters 1 thru -1 of text document 1
```

The **Event Log** and **Result** of this *example* **AppleScript** *code* is:

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    get selection
        --> insertion point before character 1 of text document 1
    count every word of insertion point before character 1 of text document 1
        --> 0
    get characters 1 thru -1 of text document 1
        --> characters 1 thru 499 of text document 1
    count every word of characters 1 thru 499 of text document 1
        --> 70
    replace "(" using "(" searching in characters 1 thru 499 of text document 1 options {search mode:literal, starting at top:false, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false}
        --> 3
end tell
Result:
3
```

As you can see it replaces the three `(` in:

```
set var_1 to (replace "(" using "(" searching in my_selection options {search mode:literal, starting at top:false, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false})
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, this change nothing :(

Comment: Another point: if I perform a keystroke "a" using command down then a keystroke "c" using command down, this will cut the text to the clipboard. But here, he clipboard stay empty. Meaning the cmd+A and Cmd+C has no effect (and so I can't get the new selection). Strange...

Comment: @Peter, I beg to differ with you, it does change things, however I've updated my answer because there is absolutely no need whatsoever to use UI Scripting when `set my_selection to characters 1 thru -1 of text document 1` is all that necessary when `if nb_mot < 1`!

Comment: With the new answer, it works. Only with the activate, it does nothing more, but  wih "set my_selection to characters 1 thru -1 of text document 1" that's OK. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter, For the record, the code in the OP didn't do a ⌘C, only a ⌘A and it wasn't working because TextWrangler never had focus. In my original answer to you, adding `activate` did in fact allow select all the text, however, if you added a ⌘C after the `display dialog "Select all"` line of code then this is why it's not copied to the clipboard because the dialog box removed focus. If you added `tell application "TextWrangler" to activate` after the dialog box and before the ⌘C, it would copy to the clipboard. But ⌘C was not discussed in the OP in the first place and therefore irrelevant AFAIC.

Comment: @Peter, UI Scripting can be totally dependent on focus and timing and the bottom line is UI Scripting should always be avoided if it can be coded without using it.

Comment: concerning the ⌘A ⌘C I've tried without the dialog, in order to not loose the focus but nothing was selected and of course nothing copied.  As I have notice a few instabilty in TextWrangler under High Sierra 10.13.2, maybe there is a link. Actually, the "characters 1 thru -1" method resolve my problem. So that's OK.

Comment: @Peter, The **⌘A ⌘C** works for me because I'm using a supported version of TextWrangler on a supported version of OS X. From [TextWrangler](https://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), **TextWrangler is [not compatible](https://www.barebones.com/support/new-os.html) with macOS 10.13 (High Sierra)**, and is in all likelihood why it's not working for you. You might want to switch to BBEdit. In any case, my comment regarding UI Scripting stands and I'm glad I could offer you one of other ways possible to get things working for you.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

```
property currentSelection : ""
property selectAll : ""
property oldClipboard : ""

copy (the clipboard) to oldClipboard

tell application "TextWrangler"
    set currentSelection to contents of selection
    if currentSelection is not "" then
        set the clipboard to currentSelection
    else
        tell its document 1 -- assuming the document in question is document 1
            select every text
        end tell
        set selectAll to contents of selection
        set the clipboard to selectAll
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Problem is that you loose the previous content of the clipboard while with user3439894's answer, you preserve the clipboard content.

Comment: I just updated the code to copy the old clipboard content To be stored in a property variable which you can access if needed

Comment: @Peter You can also comment out the copy commands If you don't need them

Comment: your code is OK why a small change: in the else, rather than tell its document1... and so on, just put 2 lines: "select every text of text document 1" and "set my_selection to (get selection)". Strangly, under OSX 10.13.2, the "select every text" after the "tell" give a message telling text is unknown. But maybe that's a TextWrangler issue as it not very "stable" on High Sierra. Thanks!